# Why doesn't costmap clear the old obstacles outside the scanner scope?

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't upload the snapshot. So hopfully I can make the issue clear.

When I was using turtlebot to navigate along the known map, the costmap would inflate the static map which is fairly well. The XTion scanner found the obstacles marked as yellow which was removed  after a while. The scanner was not aware of this new situation because was outside the scanner scope at the moment. I setup a new destination on the map but ROS reported Failed to find the route on the map. It was caused by those obstacles who were in the way minutes ago.

I wonder why costmap doesn’t remove the out of date obstacles in a given period? In this situation how to make the ROS navigation stack figure out a route?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215445/why-doesn%27t-costmap--clear-the-old-obstacles-outside-the-scanner-scope?/) by [Dragon Qu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21428/dragon-qu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-08-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sidd is correct. The costmap aims to keep the map up to date with the most recent information it got. If it sees obstacles and then moves away without clearing them, it will keep that information forever (or until new sensor data clears the obstacles).

If this causes no path to be found, the recovery behaviors should trigger to clear the obstacles.

If you wish not to remember this data at all, you can remove the obstacles layer from your global costmap, and the obstacle layer in the local costmap will keep you from hitting obstacles.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jackiescay](https://answers.ros.org/users/32041/jackiescay/) on 2017-09-27**:
David, thanks for answering this. Could you possibly give more specifics for how to remove the obstacles layer from the global costmap? For example, what files do I need to modify/how?
New to ROS- thanks so much.

**Comment by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on 2018-06-06**:
FYI - I just submitted a PR that adds an `obstacle_timeout` parameter to voxel_layer, which removes obstacles from the voxel grid, using a timeout based on each voxel's insertion time.
https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/pull/740

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the sensor does not see new objects, it will not clear the object out of the map and retains the previous valid information it received. The costmap will retain the previous data (retain the presence of the previous obstacle) until it gets fresh data from it's sensor indicating that there is no obstacle.

One way to get around this is to create a node that would fill the rest of the laser scan with max range (~20m) so that the maps would be cleared. This is code for the node -

https://github.com/clubcapra/Ibex/blob/master/src/capra_lidar/scripts/max_range.py

However you must keep in mind that it isn't completely safe - if something blocks the laser or it fails your robot will drive straight into things, which is why it's not the default.

---

Originally posted by [Sidd](https://answers.ros.org/users/22657/sidd/) with karma: 155 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

don't include obstacles layer in the costmap_common_params or global_costmap_params insert it only in local_costmap_params

I mean this part or alternative depend on how you configure your obstacles layer

> observation_sources: scan   scan:
> {sensor_frame: base_scan, data_type:
> LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true,
> clearing: true}

however it'll effect global path planner behavior. otherwise you can clear using this service

> rosservice call
> /move_base/clear_costmaps "{}"

---

Originally posted by [Ahmed Osman](https://answers.ros.org/users/36991/ahmed-osman/) with karma: 56 on 2020-09-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2